# How do I save and reload a session in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, session

I want to save a session (open buffers) and then restore it at a later date. How can I do this easily in Emacs?

I'm using version 24.2.1.

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in [the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html).

Basically, you call

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

in your init file. After that, the current directory where Emacs starts determines which session is saved/loaded.

Comment: I always start Emacs from the Linux dash, so I don't really know what you're suggesting here.

Comment: Then you're probably always running emacs from your home directory. Meaning that the file describing your session will be stored there, and you will always start emacs with the same session. Now, that doesn't prevent you from saving/loading other sessions. As explained in the documentation linked above, you can type `M-x desktop-change-dir` to switch to the session saved in a particular directory.